# Number of pairs of a and b given w

Tags: math, bitwise-and

Given two statements

```
  1) w + a = b
  2) a & b = 0   (bitwise and)
```

Find the number of pairs of a and b given w.

Can someone please help me how should i solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not about programming

Answer (score 0):

There are inifinite number of pairs. Example for `w=11bin`

```
w = b - a

1001    b  
0110    a
  11    w

10001    b
01110    a
   11    w

1..k zeros..1
0..k ones...0
           11
```

We can build similar infinite sequence of pairs for the leftmost 1-bit of any given value `w`

Comment: sorry I have edited the question. 
The value of w will be given. Can u then generalize with an algorithm to solve this

Comment: I know that `w` is given. For any given `w` we can build similar infinite sequence for the leftmost 1 bit.